# Android CheckedTextView - Changing checked status on click

Tags: android, listviewitem, checkedtextview

I have a listview that needs to be multiple choice (i.e each list item has a checkbox which can be checked / unchecked)
The list view is in a tabhost and is the content for teh first tab.

My set up is like so:

My tab is set up with:

```
TabSpec tab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Services");

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("Services").setContent(new Intent(this, ServiceList.class)));
```

When the tab is clicked new activity ServiceList is started

ServiceList is defined as such:

```
    public class ServiceList extends ListActivity{
        private EscarApplication application;
        ListView listView;
         @Override
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.service_list);
             ServiceList.this.application = (EscarApplication) this.getApplication();
             final ListView listView = getListView();
         }

         protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            String.valueOf(id);
            Long.toString(id);
            ((CheckedTextView) v).setChecked(true);
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        }

         @Override
         public void onStart() {
             super.onStart();
            //Generate and display the List of visits for this day by calling the AsyncTask
             GenerateServiceList services = new GenerateServiceList();
             int id = ServiceList.this.application.getVisitId();
             services.execute(id);
             listView  = getListView();
             listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
         }

        //The AsyncTask to generate a list
         private class GenerateServiceList extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, Cursor> {
              // can use UI thread here
              protected void onPreExecute() {
              }
              // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
              protected Cursor doInBackground(Integer...params) {
                  int client_id = params[0];
                  ServiceList.this.application.getServicesHelper().open();
                  Cursor cur = ServiceList.this.application.getServicesHelper().getPotentialVisitServices(client_id);
                  return cur; 

              }
              // can use UI thread here
              protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cur){  
                  startManagingCursor(cur);
                  // the desired columns to be bound
                  String[] columns = new String[] {ServicesAdapter.KEY_SERVICE};
                  // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
                  int[] to = new int[] {R.id.display_service};
                  SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ServiceList.this, R.layout.service_list_element, cur, columns, to);
                  // set this adapter as your ListActivity's adapter
                  ServiceList.this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
ServiceList.this.application.getServicesHelper().close();       

              }
         }
    }
```

So, everything works ok until I click on my list item to change the checkbox state.

The part of teh code set to handle click events is causing me problems:

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                String.valueOf(id);
                Long.toString(id);
                ((CheckedTextView) v).setChecked(true);
                super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            }
```

My understanding is that the View v passed to the onListItemClick method reperesents my list element, so I am trying to cast v as a CheckedTextView and set teh checked value to true, however this just causes my app to crash. Am I missing something simple here, or is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks

Kevin

Comment: Can you show the exact stacktrace or logcat output from the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you debugged it to check if 'v' is null? If so, you need to use a layoutInflator to retrieve the view.

```
if(v == null)
{
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.service_list, null);
}
```